# Is installing blinds a DIY Project?

Tags: windows, installation, blinds, diy-vs-pro

My wife and I have been in our home for a little less than a year, and the paper blinds are starting to get tired to look at. The prices on blinds.com look appealing, but I'm hoping there are no hidden *gotchas* I'm not aware of.

The majority of my windows would only be one piece, there are a couple of windows that would require two blinds, and a couple would require three. We are looking at horizontal blinds also and not vertical.

My self-assessed 'DIY Level' is pretty high by my standards, just to give some background, I do the majority of the repairs on my car, and as for the home I painted the living room ceiling, walls, and baseboards all different colors, and replaced all the electrical outlets in the same room.

So, my question is: Is this something that the average home-owner can tackle? of course the blinds.com website says so, but of course I have to take the question to Stack Exchange. I've seen [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/2746/what-projects-should-never-be-diy), I didn't read every answer but I did a search for blinds and it hadn't come up *yet*, so that's a plus.

**Update 11/5/2013**

The blinds project has gone pretty smooth up until this point. It seems that some walls have plaster or sheetrock behind it. Probably not a big deal, but I've snapped a couple of [quality drill bits](http://www.homedepot.com/p/DEWALT-14-Piece-Titanium-Drill-Bit-Set-DW1354/202019930#.UnkeByTkuak) in the process. The proper method for this should be posed as a separate question imagine, so I'll do just that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My 70 year old grandma just put up new blinds in her house last year.  She did borrow my makita.

Quick Tips

- make sure you are putting your screws into either the window frame, wood framing, or use anchors
- make sure your blinds are level so if blinds are outside of window frame either use a level or take a measurement from the top of each side
- cut blinds out so that the bottom barely hits window bottom

Comment: you are 36 and your grandma is only 70 ??

Comment: well she is 74.  Didn't want him to feel that bad.

Comment: On the other side of this I didn't mention that she put up like one blind a day for about 2 weeks.  She said the first time it took her 2 hours.  She is meticulous.  Her house has to look perfect.  The rest she said took about 45 mins.  She did have me bring over anchors for a couple windows.  +1 for granny!

Answer (score 1):

I can't talk about uninstalling your current blinds. Although, I found installing blinds pretty easy and fast. To be honest, the hardest part is probably taking the width of your windows, especially if you mount them inside. Most manufacturers will tell you in advance that you are responsible for your measures.

In short, you need a measuring tape, a screwdriver and screws.  It's definitively something you can do.